# ESR rule when sorting is done on a field inside of a embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

```
{
  tests: [
    { grade: 90  },
    { grade: 80  },
    { grade: 100 },
    ...
  ]
}
```

This is the schema of my collection.

I have an index on `tests.grade`.

In my aggregation pipeline, after `$elemMatch` inside of a `$match`, there will be

```
[
  { $match: { tests: { $elemMatch: { grade: { $gt: 50 } } } } },
  { $sort: { "tests.grade": 1 } },
  { $limit: 10 }
]
```

My question is, will this work, given that `tests.grade` is a field inside of an array of embedded documents? Would it know to use the embedded doc that was matched in the `elemMatch`? What if there are multiple matches? Would this be optimized as in ESR rule?

Comment: Neither `$elemMatch` nor `$match` will remove elements from the array.

Comment: I know that. So are you saying the sorting will not work?

Comment: Considering [how arrays are sorted](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#arrays), a multi-key index wouldn't be much help for the sort.

Comment: Based on the two questions at the end of the description, I suspect that this pipeline is not doing what you expect. _All_ `tests.grade` values from the matching documents (not just those that pass the `$elemMatch` predicate) will be considered for the sort. This is, I believe, what @Joe's two comments together are stating as well. I think [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2oA69GnSBP3) provides a good demonstration. In short - the index will help with the `$match` but not with the `$sort`.